# ScrolltoIndex is inconsistently returning to index 0 at the end in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a strange behavior where the Slider I made sometimes returns to index 0 (first slide), but most times it returns to index 1. I made a Sandbox in case you need it, but I can't figure out how to make expo work in sandbox.

[**HERE**](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/modern-water-r8lj7x) is the sandbox

Here's the code for that view

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Animated, FlatList, View, Text, Image, Dimensions, Pressable } from "react-native";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Making Testing Easier",
    img: "https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/85/884/desktop-wallpaper-beautiful-judo-throws-judoka-thumbnail.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Instructional Videos",
    img: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/84/c9/2b84c904ec3373b90f4fcad956233211.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Newaza Fully Expanded",
    img: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d4/55/8c/d4558cf325344900b9eead6cb74dab20.jpg",
  },
];

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const CustomButton = ({ onPress, title, btnstyle, textstyle }) => {
  return (
    <Pressable style={btnstyle} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={textstyle}>{title}</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

const SlideItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.slideitemcontainer}>
      <View style={styles.overlay}>
        <Image source={item.img} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.txtcontent}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.btncontent}>
        <CustomButton
          title="Get Started"
          btnstyle={styles.btnPrimary}
          textstyle={styles.btnPrimaryText}
        />
        <CustomButton
          title="Login"
          btnstyle={styles.btnSecondary}
          textstyle={styles.btnSecondaryText}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Pagination = ({ data, scrollX }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.paginationcontainer}>
      {data.map((_, idx) => {
        const inputRange = [(idx - 1) * width, idx * width, (idx + 1) * width];

        const dotWidth = scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange,
          outputRange: [12, 30, 12],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        });

        const backgroundColor = scrollX.interpolate({
          inputRange,
          outputRange: [
            "rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)",
            "rgba(204, 204, 204, .7)",
            "rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)",
          ],
          extrapolate: "clamp",
        });
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={idx.toString()}
            style={[styles.dot, { width: dotWidth, backgroundColor }]}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const flatlistRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    Animated.event(
      [
        {
          nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: {
              x: scrollX,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      },
    )(event);
  };

  const handleOnViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => {
    setIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
  }).current;

  const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
  }).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    flatlistRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
      behavior: "smooth",
      animated: true,
      index: index,
    });
  }, [index]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      const nextIndex = index === data.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
      setIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [index]);

  const getItemLayout = (data, index) => ({
    length: width,
    offset: width * index,
    index,
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        ref={flatlistRef}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideItem item={item} />}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        onViewableItemsChanged={handleOnViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
      />
      <Pagination data={data} scrollX={scrollX} index={index} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    opacity: 0.7,
  },
  slideitemcontainer: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    width,
  },
  txtcontent: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "25%",
    paddingHorizontal: "2%",
  },
  btncontent: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: "25%",
    width: "70%",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 45,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#fff",
  },
  btnPrimary: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 36,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: "#0079D1",
    borderColor: "#0079D1",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 2,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  btnPrimaryText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: "white",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
  btnSecondary: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 36,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 3,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderColor: "#0079D1",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  btnSecondaryText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: "#0079D1",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
  },
  usjacontainer: {
    width,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: "13%",
  },
  usja: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  paginationcontainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 35,
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 64,
    width: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  dot: {
    height: 12,
    width: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginHorizontal: 3,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)",
  },
  dotActive: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.secondary,
  },
});
```

More specifically, the useEffect is probably where I am messing up

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        const nextIndex = index === data.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
        setIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [index]);
```

SIDENOTE - Is there a way to make it so that the animation only moves forward, rather than a backwards slide to 0? Infinity scroll is always so much more pleasant.

Comment: Instead of resetting the index to 0, would increment it and use the modulo (`%`) operator with the length of the data array be enough? That should create an infinite loop effect: `const nextIndex = (index + 1) % data.length;`

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i see there might be two reasons for this to happen:

- **Synchronous Update of index (Race Condition)**: When setIndex(nextIndex) is called, the
  update to the index does not happen immediately. It's scheduled for the
  next render. This means that during the 2000 ms interval, other
  parts of your code might interact with the index, potentially
  causing unexpected behaviour.
- **Dependence on index**: The effect runs whenever index changes. If
  something else in your code changes index (like user interaction),
  the effect will run and might not behave as expected.

**Suggested Solution**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    setIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex === data.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1));
  }, 2000);
  return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, []);
```

- use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. This allows the function
  inside to be called every 2000 ms without re-initializing the timer
  on every `index` change.
- The dependency array is empty, ensuring the interval is set up once
  and not reset on every `index` change.
- use a functional update (`setIndex(prevIndex => ...)`) to ensure we
  always have the correct previous index.

### Infinite Loop (Circular Carousel)

to create this effect there are three things to consider:

1. **Duplicating First and Last Items**: Add the last item to the beginning
   of your data array and the first item to the end. This creates the
   illusion that the carousel loops infinitely.
2. **Adjusting the Initial Index**: Start the carousel at the first "real"
   item (which is now at index 1, since you've added an item at the
   beginning).
3. **Handling the End of the Scroll**: When the user reaches the end of the
   carousel, reset to the second item without animation. Similarly,
   when they scroll to the beginning, reset to the second-to-last item.

here is a basic guideline:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Animated, FlatList,
  View, Text, Image, Dimensions, Pressable
} from "react-native";

// Original data array
const originalData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Making Testing Easier",
    img: "https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/85/884/desktop-wallpaper-beautiful-judo-throws-judoka-thumbnail.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Instructional Videos",
    img: "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2b/84/c9/2b84c904ec3373b90f4fcad956233211.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Newaza Fully Expanded",
    img: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/d4/55/8c/d4558cf325344900b9eead6cb74dab20.jpg",
  },
];

// Modify the data array for infinite loop
const loopedData = [originalData[originalData.length - 1], ...originalData, originalData[0]];

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

// ... Rest of your components (CustomButton, SlideItem, Pagination)

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1); // Start from the second item (first real item)
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const flatlistRef = useRef(null);

  // Automatic index change
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex === loopedData.length - 1 ? 1 : prevIndex + 1));
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  // Handle index change for looping
  useEffect(() => {
    if (index === 0 || index === loopedData.length - 1) {
      // No animation when resetting the index
      flatlistRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index: index === 0 ? loopedData.length - 2 : 1, animated: false });
    } else {
      flatlistRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index: index, animated: true });
    }
  }, [index]);

  // ... Rest of your code

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={loopedData}
        ref={flatlistRef}
        keyExtractor={(item, idx) => `slide-${idx}`}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideItem item={item} />}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        snapToAlignment="center"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: false }
        )}
        onViewableItemsChanged={({ viewableItems }) => {
          if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
            setIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
          }
        }}
        viewabilityConfig={{ itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50 }}
        initialScrollIndex={1}
        getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
          length: width,
          offset: width * index,
          index,
        })}
      />
      <Pagination data={loopedData} scrollX={scrollX} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

// ... Styles
```

### Enhanced Solution for Smooth Transition

You can implement a slight delay and a smooth scrolling animation to achieve a fluid and animated transition when the carousel loops back to the first slide.

This can be done by:

1. **Animating the Scroll**: Instead of instantly resetting the index, use
   an animated scroll to the target index. This creates a smoother
   transition.
2. **Delaying the Reset**: Implement a short delay before resetting the
   index to the first slide. This gives the illusion of a continuous
   loop.

Here is a revised version of your React Native code incorporating these changes:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Animated, FlatList,
  View, Text, Image, Dimensions, Pressable
} from "react-native";

// ... [Your existing code and data]

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1); // Start from the second item (first real item)
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToIndex = (index, animated) => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollToOffset({ offset: index * width, animated });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      let nextIndex = index === loopedData.length - 1 ? 1 : index + 1;
      scrollToIndex(nextIndex, true);
      setIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [index]);

  // ... [Rest of your code]
};

// ... [Rest of your components]

export default App;
```

Comment: I'll accept it as an answer because it does fix the most important issue (consistently  return to the first slide). I appreciate this man. Thanks. I'm not exactly satisfied with the hard jump to the first slide. I was expecting it to be more fluid and animated. But I wont be picky about it :) Maybe on another question :)

Comment: I've added an enhanced solution :) let me know if it works well, Im kind of eyeballing it cause your example is not working

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make the sandbox work too, but their emulator is crashing. This added the first slide at the end so it behaves the same only I get the first slide twice now. It still has that rewind. Unless I missed something. I'll take another look over your code